# Date::Manip::Delta - the number of seconds

Tags: perl, date, time

How to convert a Date::Manip::Delta value into the number of seconds? (Perl)

I calculate:

```
my $date1 = Date::Manip::Date->new;
$date1->parse($h1->{ReqTime});
my $dateNext = Date::Manip::Date->new;
$dateNext->parse($hNext->{ReqTime});
my $delta = $date1->calc($dateNext);
```

Now I need to convert `$delta` into the number of seconds.

Comment: Also check [Date::Manip - Working with Epoch](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.46/lib/Date/Manip/Examples.pod#WORKING_WITH_EPOCH)

Comment: Any particular reason for using Date::Manip? DateTime is much friendlier to use